# Freemarker function that return map value

Tags: java, freemarker

I have some map in Java

```
    Map<SomeEnum, Boolean> someClassMap = new HashMap <SomeClass, Boolean>();
    someClassMap.put(SomeEnum.EXAMPLE_A, true);
    etc.
```

now in ftl I'd like to create function that will return value from map (ofc by given key)

```
<#function checkAccess someEnumName>
    <#list someClassMap?keys as key>
        <#if someEnumName== ${key}>
            <#return ${someClassMap[key]} >
        </#if>
    </#list> 
</#function>
```

So this code suppose to check if given parameter in function equals to key from map then return value of that key from map.

Unfortunetly I'm getting this error (its pointing at `<#if>` and `<#return>`:

> Encountered "{" at line 3, column 37 in functions.ftl. Was
>   expecting one of:
>       ">" ...
>       "." ...
>       "[" ...
>       "(" ...
>       "?" ...
>       "!" ...
>        ...
>       "??" ...
>       "+" ...
>       "-" ...
>       "*" ...
>       "/" ...
>       "%" ...
>       ">=" ...
>        ...
>       ">" ...
>        ...
>        ...
>        ...
>       ".." ...
>        ...
>        ...

As I understand I can't return values like this but unfortunetly I have no idea how to do this. I also tried to `<#assign ... >` but same error appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you mix Freemarker tags with interpolation (**${}**).
Freemarker tries to render/print the String value of **x** when calling **${x}** .

---

So when you do:

```
<#if someEnumName== ${key}>
```

and

```
<#return ${someClassMap[key]} >
```

Freemarker will try to print `${key}` and `${someClassMap[key]}`.

---

Mixing interpolation in Freemarker tags is incorrect syntax, causing Freemarker to complain.
Simply remove the **${}** and you should be fine.

See following for more info:

1. [Freemarker template structure (Interpolation vs Freemarker tags)](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_overallstructure.html)
2. [Interpolation (check the section with "Warning!")](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_stringop_interpolation)

Comment: any idea how to call that function with string argument? `${checkAccess("test")` does not work for me, also if i assign test to variable and pass that variable as argument function it doesnt work too

Comment: I am not sure what "does not work" means, but I'm guessing that **<#if someEnumName== ${key}>** is never true, so you never return anything.

Possible problems:
 1.  someClassMap?keys is empty so you never iterate over anything with **<#list someClassMap?keys as key>**

2.  someEnumName is a String, and key is a SomeEnum.  When you compare **someEnumName== key**, it's possible that the comparison being done is **someEnumName== key.toString()** which may not be what you expect.

Comment: `checkAccess("test")` returns a boolean, so `${true}` will print **true** and `${false}` will print nothing. So instead try `${checkAccess("test")?string}`. See [link](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html)